# Vulnerability in SHA functions while loose compressing data?

Tags: security, cryptography, bitcoin, sha

IF, someone was able to retrieve the intentionally lost information from the SHA function by finding a vulnerability in the loose compression of data & able to get the input of every SHA256 output & verify a block that does not belong in the main BTC network, can't it be used to create a fake dust transaction and manually verify that transaction? - Ultimately creating an unlimited BTC in seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that for a given SHA256 output there may be **several** inputs that result to the given SHA256 output.

AFAIK Bitcoin strongly relies on not being able to reverse SHA256 function. So without talking about faking blocks or making dust transactions, if you are able to reverse the SHA256, then you can instantly mine Bitcoin blocks making you reward all the remaining bitcoins not yet mined. However if such an extreme miner appeared, he would be spotted by the whole network and so the value of bitcoins would be lost as the network isn't working as it was designed.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by for a given `SHA256` output, there may be several inputs that result into the given output? Are you referring to the theoretical possibility or the result in practice? The statement that `several inputs result to a given output` violates the second-preimage resistance property of the hash function `H(x) != H(x') where x != x'`

Comment: I don't know precisely `SHA256` but AFAIK we can provide it an arbitrary long sequence of bits as input and the `SHA256` hash function will always return an output of 256 bits. Thanks to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) we can deduce that there exists a hash such that there is another input that results in the same hash. Even if in theory it is ["computationally infeasible"](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ssw/cs355/hash.pdf). The OP question was about what would be involved if the `SHA256` hash function was having a vulnerability.

Comment: To be clear, there are infinitely many inputs for a given output of SHA256. SHA256 has a fixed size output but takes an arbitrary size input, by the pigeon-hole principle infinitely many collisions must exist. Second-preimage resistance says that finding such collisions is nonetheless hard. Reversing a hash function is also hard (preimage resistance) but the question here is asking about second preimage resistance. Being able to reverse a hash wouldn't necessarily help you break the bitcoin protocol. You might just find the public input, or find a different input in the wrong format.